# I can not seem to attach my images of choice from my computer on my carousel on my website. My carousel is three images

Tags: html, image, carousel

I can not seem to attach my images of choice from my computer files containing images on my carousel for my website. My carousel is of three images. i already have the jpegs/pngs of choice and know what ones i want to use but the carousel returns with a broken picture on top left hand corner

```
 <div class="container">
      <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <!-- Wrapper for slides for images-->
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
          <div class="item active">
            <img src="la.jpg" alt="First Slide" style="width:100%;">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h3>some text</span></h3>
            </div>
          </div>
    <!-- image 2 -->
          <div class="item">
            <img src="chicago.jpg" alt="Second Slide" style="width:100%;">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h3>some text</span></h3>
            </div>
          </div>
        <!-- image 3-->
          <div class="item">
            <img src="ny.jpg" alt="Third Slide" style="width:100%;">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h3>some text</span></h3>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Left and right controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have specified the correct path to your images.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me, thanks for the suggestion, however i did consider the path as i tried from various paths, like my desktop etc,  but still unable. Are you or forward this issue to anyone else, which may be able to provide other variations as my coding level is not at expert level. Many thanks